# textFieldShouldBeginEditing is not firing for the correct textfield in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am not sure why `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` returns all of the `UiTextField`

File: PaymentViewControllerDummy.swift

```
  class PaymentViewControllerDummy: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var dobTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dobTextField.tag = 1
        nameTextField.tag = 2

        dobTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        println("Tage From textFile: \(textField.tag) ")
        println("Tage From dobTextField: \(dobTextField.tag) ")

        if(textField.tag == dobTextField.tag) {
            println("You are editing date of birth")

            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

All the IBOutlets are connected. This is very standard code. I have done this times after time however whichever textfield I press `textField == self.dobTextField` comes back `true`

Console result:

[image]

Am I missing something?

**Edit**

Here is the Interface builder screens

[image]

[image]

***NOTE***

I made a standalone project and copy the codes to the project and it worked as it should however it is not working in this project. Could it be something in the `StoryBoard` ?

Comment: have you double checked if you're Outlets are connected correctly ? It could be 2 outlets connected to the same textfield on your storyboard...

Comment: Here you go, I have updated the question with the shots of Interface builder

Comment: Are there any other connections coming from the text fields? Check in the connections inspector, or ctrl click on the field. It does appear that both fields are connected to the `dobTextField` since they are both returning the same tag and are also both firing the event even though only the `dobTextField` is the only one set up with its delegate (clicking on the name text field shouldn't do anything). Try removing all connections to both fields and reconnecting them to their respective outlets.

Comment: I deleted the Main.StoryBoard completely. Then recreated the fields, same result. I create a new project and do the same thing and everything works fine. Very Strange!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to access text fields in text field did editing method is via `tags`. Set the tag of both the text fields let say `self.dobTextField.tag=1` & `self.nameTextField.tag=2`. Then in

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool 
        println(textField.tag)
        println(dobTextField.tag)

        if(textField.tag == 1) //dob text field is currently in edit mode 
        {
            println("You are editing date of birth")
            return true 
        }
        else  // name text field is in edit mode 
        {
            return true
        }
}
```

Comment: Just updated my question. It makes no difference. Condition passes even when I tap on `nameTextField`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't check UI objects with equality comparison.

You had better use tags (or maybe labels, not preferred however) in order to conduct protocol calls over different UI objects.

```
class PaymentViewControllerDummy: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var dobTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dobTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        println(textField.tag)
        println(dobTextField.tag)

        if(textField.tag == dobTextField.tag) {
            println("You are editing date of birth")

            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Also you **DON'T** have to refer `self` if you want to access instance variables, if you are not in a block (closure).

Comment: Just updated my question. It makes no difference. Condition passes even when I tap on `nameTextField`

Comment: @MrH did you try to print each?

Comment: I have updated the Console print out. First I tapped the `dobTextField` Then I tapped the `nameTextField` Both got me the same result.

Comment: @MrH It looks like you defined similar tags to the text fields. Change them in IB first, if it doesn't solve, change them programmatically. Clean the project in every step, build and run.

Comment: I set the tag programatically still the same thing. One thing though I have got 2 more UITextField in there which has nothing there even if I tap on them the delegation triggers. Those UITextFields don't have even IBOutlet.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check the Note that I put in the Question.